# Calling another GRPC service from a constructor

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

In GRPC...what is the most efficient of calling another GRPC service before it can answer to any request?

My code here looks a bit of a mess... in the constructor of the GreetingServiceImpl, I am starting a Thread just to get
some sort of Greetings list from a GreetingServiceRepository service running on a different port?

So the use case is something like this... There is a GRPC service GreetingsRepository which contains a list of greetings and
a GreetingServiceImpl which calls the GreetingsRepository.. I wanted to customize the response so that I can return a custom response
for every request....

```
public class MyGrpcServer {
  static public void main(String [] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
        .addService(new GreetingServiceImpl()).build();

    System.out.println("Starting server...");
    server.start();
    System.out.println("Server started!");
    server.awaitTermination();
  }

  public static class GreetingServiceImpl extends GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceImplBase {

    public GreetingServiceImpl(){
        init();
    }
    public void init(){
        //Do initial long running task
        //Like running a thread that will call another service from a repository
        Thread t1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                //Call another grpc service
                 ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8081)
                    .usePlaintext(true)
                    .build();

                GreetingServiceRepository.eGreetingServiceRepositoryBlockingStub stub =
                    GreetingServiceRepositoryGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
                //Do something with the response
            }
        }
        t1.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void greeting(HelloRequest request, StreamObserver<HelloResponse> responseObserver) {
      System.out.println(request);

      //USE THE LIST OF GREETINGS FROM THE REPOSITORY and customize it per user
      //String greeting = "Hello there, " + request.getName();
      //String greeting = "Holla, " + request.getName();
      String greeting = "Good Morning, " + request.getName();

      HelloResponse response = HelloResponse.newBuilder().setGreeting(greeting).build();

      responseObserver.onNext(response);
      responseObserver.onCompleted();
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way in GRPC to initialize the service before it can respond to any other request?
I am not sure if constructor is a good idea..and firing up another thread just to call another service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two major ways: 1) delay starting the server until dependent services are ready, and 2) delay clients sending requests to this server, until dependent services are ready.

Delay starting the server until ready:

```
GreetingServiceImpl gsi = new GreetingServiceImpl();
Server server = ServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
    .addService(gsi).build();

System.out.println("Starting server...");
gsi.init();
server.start();
```

Delaying clients sending requests to this server depends on how clients learn of the server's address. For example, if using a load balancing proxy that uses the `Health` service, wait until ready and then call:

```
healthStatusManager.setStatus("", ServingStatus.SERVING);
```

The proxy will then learn this server is healthy and inform clients about the backend.

Comment: Ohh so this is what I did... I fired up a thread in the init method to call my greeting repository and wait for it to finish then start the server.